# Reading sequential file in cobol

Tags: cobol, mainframe

Is there any way to read a sequential file in cobol many times? For example you reached the end of the file then go back from the beggining of the file?

Answer (score 2):

Close the file, reopen it and re-read.

I'm interested to know why you'd want to do this?

Comment: Hi TrueDub, I am doing a search on the occurence of a string in file 1 from the items in file 2 but there are no keys. Thanks for the superb reply though.

Comment: Would it be easier to read the file into an array and simply search that each time? It would surely be faster but you might encounter memory issues if it's a huge file.

Comment: In that case, `JOINKEYS` of `DFSORT` helps alot. I strongly dont suggest your approach if your requirement is ONLY to search for the string from file1 with the list of strings in file2...

Answer (score 2):

You could also read the file inside a loop or perform varying. Like the other answer, make sure you close the file out each time you reach the end and reopen it.

Comment: Hi Bill, reopening the file can reach up to a thousand reopens, which I think would be too costly and inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, `JOINKEYS` of `DFSORT` helps alot. I strongly dont suggest your approach if your requirement is ONLY to search for the string from file1 with the list of strings in file2.

Comment: Hi Raja, Joinkeys nor dfsort wont help since there are no keys and nothing to sort. File 1 is garbage and file 2 has a single string per line. The goal is to find that single string in file 1 per line from file 2. If that certain string was found in file 1, put a flag on that string in file 2 then get the next item in the next line, then look for the occurence of the string in file 1 from the top.

Comment: I get it... but still try to incorporate if you feel you can use them... I feel you had thought... go ahead with your cobol program logic only... If you still need some suggestion, put a brief of the requirement with file layouts and lrecls.. may try to resolve...

Answer (score 0):

An alternative: make a copy of file 1 with a utility (or another COBOL program).  The copy, file 1a, has ORGANIZATION RELATIVE (a VSAM RRDS, perhaps).  In your scanning/matching program, you can reposition to the first record of file 1a with the START statement.

Equivalently, you could make an indexed-sequential file 1a, where the key is just an arbitrary ascending number that happens to be the same as the record number.

Answer (score 0):

It would be plain silly to open, process, close, re-open, reprocess, re-close, for any number of times, let alone up to 1,000. It is very, very, time consuming.

With a Cobol program, you store the smaller file in a table and process the table against the larger file, as has been suggested.

However, you don't need a program. JOINKEYS *will* give you the solution.

You don't have a key? Oh, dear, dear. You make one. You make the same one-byte key, with the same value, for each record on both files. Do the JOINKEYS on that key. Specify SORTED on the JOINKEYS (and NOSEQCK if you have DFSORT) You have a "Cartesian" Join. Use  SS (a Sub-String match) which can be for the entire record, or part of the record. Your actual required output is unclear, and I don't suppose you're going to come up with that now.

With DFSORT you can do it in one step. With SyncSort you can do it in one step if your version supports JNFnCMTL files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

File1 has reocrds plus a key
File2 has reocrds where key occurs many times

I store file1 details into an array, this mean u must know size of data

I scan file2 until end of file, if key in file2 match key in array then do your computation,

Example
Store 1 2 3 4 in array from File1, until EOF of File1
Scan file2 having  1 1 4 4 2 3
If 1 in file2  match 1 in array then compute
Keep doing until u reach end of File2

Hope it helps